# react-native fill the picker by mapping

Tags: react-native, picker

on my RN project, I'm trying to fill my `Picker` by mapping from the state, which is an array. I consoled the object during mapping and it seems there isn't any problem, it shows the object that is being mapped. What I am doing wrong? Can you help me, please?

```
<Item>
                        <Picker
                                iosHeader="Select one"
                                mode="dropdown"
                                onValueChange={this.onBranchChange.bind(this)}>
                                {this.state.branchAddresses.map((address,i) =>
                                     {
                                         console.log("myAddresses: ",address);
                                         return <Item style={{fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro-Regular'}} label={address.id} value={address.id} key={i}/>}
                                )}
                            </Picker>
                        </Item>
```

And here is the snapshot of `console.log()`.It writes the objects without any problem.[image]

[image]

Here is the warning that I get.
[image]
[image]

Comment: why is your `Picker` wrapped into an `Item`?

Comment: I wrapped it with Item in order to draw the line between the Picker and the component below. But, after your comment I tried it without Item. again it does not show anything, just a warning on an empty,white page. - I added snapshot of warning to the question, as well.

Comment: I think you are importing `Item` again from react-native. You should now use one of the two ways described in my answer.

Comment: Yeap, it solved my problem. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `Item` from the `Picker` component to get this work.

There are two possible ways to do it.

`const PickerItem = Picker.Item;`

and than using this `<PickerItem>` component later on.

Or you just use the Component directly

`<Picker.Item style={{fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro-Regular'}} label={address.id} value={address.id} key={i}/>`

Comment: no,it is 'Item' component of 'react-native'. I put it there to draw the line between Picker and the next/below component.

Comment: You should use the `Item` from `Picker` to render the options.

You could also do it like this: return `<Picker.Item .../>`

Answer (score 1):

You should use ..!

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {

  StyleSheet,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios'
import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';

export default function App() {

  const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  const fetchAPI = () => {
    const result = axios.post('http://www.example.com')
      .then(response => {
        const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)).data.listaIncidencia;
        setState(data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    return result;
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAPI();
  }, []); 
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("DEFAULD");

  console.log(selectedValue)
  return (
    <View>
      <Picker
        selectedValue={selectedValue}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}>{
          state.map((item, index) => {
            return <Picker.Item value={item.idMotivo} label={item.motivoDesc} key={index} />
          })
        }
      </Picker>
    </View>
  );
}
```